# Installation stuck at xubuntu ubiquity: Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed - how can I overcome this?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

When trying to install Xubuntu 13.10, it always stops at

```
xubuntu ubiquity:  Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.22.1+2.00-19ubuntu2.1) ...
```

It's just stuck there. Nothing is happening, although I can continue to use the USB live mode as I am typing this post right. I am installing from a USB drive booted into UEFI because I want to dual-boot with Win 7 Pro x64, so switching to Legacy BIOS mode is out of the question unfortunately. I don't have any encrypted partition or drive.

Does anyone have any pointers how I could overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a log file with more details (check under `/root`; you'll need to use `sudo` to do so), that may give you some clues.

Beyond that, you can manually install [any EFI boot loader you like.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) The easiest to install are likely to be GRUB 2 from Ubuntu's repository (but your problem indicates this might not be so easy) and [rEFInd.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) In the case of rEFInd, it's likely to be easiest to start with the USB flash drive or CD-R image. If you can boot to Linux using that, then installing the Debian-package version should get rEFInd working as your default boot manager.

A variant on the GRUB 2 installation option is to run [Boot Repair.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) This will install a fresh copy of GRUB on the computer, so it's essentially another way to re-install GRUB.

Comment: That was me above. Thanks for your reply, Rod. I would like to provide more info but I don't have the nerve to poke around any longer today. I am confused by this. [Maybe it's because of my partitions?](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6541297/) `/sda6` is located before `sda2`, physically speaking. `sda1` is that hidden MS partition thing. Also: For the installation, I added an *additional* `biosgrub` partition before `sda4` with a size of 150 MB as you explained somewhere on here. Configuring for `/home` and new `/` was easy actually.

Comment: I can say that I have a little bit of experience with rEFInd, so I actually inquired about rEFInd already, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/378984/how-to-boot-xubuntu-with-refind) but nothing came of it. I wonder, people using rEFInd for any *buntu-version, do they let GRUB2 install itself (if it works) and then install rEFInd later? I'd like to skip GRUB2, but I guesstimate that it is impossible because of its integration, right?

Comment: Physical partition ordering not matching partition numbers is irrelevant. Whenever discussing partitions, it's critical that you provide actual output from `parted`, `gdisk`, or some other partitioning tools; verbal summaries are imprecise and invariably omit critical information. A `bios_grub` partition is *not* needed on EFI-based computers, and should be more like 1MiB in size.

Comment: The output of `parted -l`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6544859/

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your partition table. Please try the advice I gave in my answer -- namely, to install another boot loader or boot manager.

Comment: Alright, I will. In the meantime I managed to get GRUB2 working with Boot-Repair. I have now 6 (six) entries for Windows EFI files/loaders but booting works fine for both OSes.